# What does Timatic say about UK reentry on Tier 2 passport stamp

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, paperwork, timatic

What does Timatic say about UK reentry on Tier 2 passport stamp? My visa has been approved but my BRP is not ready yet. I've entered and left the UK, so my visa has been stamped but now I need to reenter.

Comment: If you have a visa, what Timatic says isn't really relevant. What is your actual concern?

Comment: My actual concern is if the airline will allow me to board and the if immigration officer will let me in.

Comment: The letter from the home office that the got with my visa says you may experience delays at the border if you leave before you get your brp. Is it as simple as saying that immigration could take an hour instead of a few minutes? Or is there some implied meaning?

Comment: @joe Is your visa sticker still valid (it's valid for 30 days normally)?

Answer (score 2):

TIMATIC always says "Visa required, except...".

Since you have a visa, if it's unexpired (it usually lasts 30 days), you can board the plane and re-enter the UK.